# How to find unconnected end points in jsPlumb?

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

In my app, I am using jsPlumb lib in one module, Is there any way to find out unconnected endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no function in [API Document](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/files/jquery-jsPlumb-1-3-16-all-js.html#jsPlumb%201.3.16) to get all endpoints, hence you need to get all the  elements having endpoints and check whether its endpoints have connections:

```
var elem = $('.havingEndpoint'); // get elements having endpoint based on its class
var emptypoints=[],k=0;          //consists of all empty endpoint objects which can be used to manipulate them
for(var i=0;i<elem.length;i++)   // for all elements having endpoints iterate
{
     var eps=jsPlumb.getEndpoints($(elem[i]));  //get all endpoints of element
     for(var j=0;j<eps.length;j++)
     {
          if(eps[j].connections.length==0)    // check no. of connections
               emptypoints[k++]=eps[j];       //if true add to emptypoints array
     }
 }
 console.log("no. of empty points: "+ k);
```